ksmbd share looks empty at client side
I'm trying to get ksmbd work on a machine running bookworm. But regardless if I'm using a Linux GUI, CLI or a Windows 10 Client, I'm unable to browse through files or directories within the mounted share.
But I'm able to create files and directory's on the ksmb server, to edit them und to remove them again.
Because all cients work the same way I guess it's a ksmbd problem. All following data are from Linux CLI
By the way, regardless if I login to the server via ssh or sshfs. The user 'henning' did always see files and directories.
Note. All files on the server within /zPool are mounts of ZFS repositories with posix acl's.
When using the share "example" from my ksmbd.conf, which points to /tmp on the server, everything works as expected.
Is this an error, or am I missing something. Did not find a hint anywhere...
lets have a look into the mountpoint before start
# vdir /mnt/NAS/
insgesamt 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 admin admins 4096 29. Jul 2020  .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root  root   4096 31. Dez 19:14 ..

mount share to local dir
# mount -t cifs //pve.dry.lan/tmp /mnt/NAS/
Password for henning@//pve.dry.lan/tmp:

no error, seems that nothing happened
client
# vdir /mnt/NAS/
insgesamt 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 12. Jun 2022  .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 31. Dez 19:14 ..

but try to create dir & file, nor errors so far
# mkdir /mnt/NAS/ksmbd-test-dir
# echo 1234 > ksmbd-text.txt

seems that nothing happened again
# vdir /mnt/NAS/
insgesamt 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 12. Jun 2022  .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 31. Dez 19:17 ..

lets look on the server, new created entry's are there
$ vdir /zPool/tmp/
...
drwxrwsr-x+  2 henning admins         2 Dec 31 19:19 ksmbd-test-dir
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 henning admins         5 Dec 31 19:20 ksmbd-test.txt
...

$ getfacl /zPool/tmp/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: zPool/tmp/
# owner: admin
# group: admins
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:admin:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:admins:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

$ getfacl /zPool/tmp/ksmbd-test
ksmbd-test-dir/ ksmbd-test.txt  
root@pve:/zPool/tmp# getfacl /zPool/tmp/ksmbd-test-dir/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: zPool/tmp/ksmbd-test-dir/
# owner: henning
# group: admins
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:admin:rwx
group::r-x
group:admins:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:admin:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:admins:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

$ getfacl /zPool/tmp/ksmbd-test.txt 
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: zPool/tmp/ksmbd-test.txt
# owner: henning
# group: admins
user::rwx
user:admin:rwx
group::r-x
group:admins:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x

finaly the ksmbd.conf
[global]
    ; global parameters
    bind interfaces only = no
    deadtime = 0
    guest account = nobody
    interfaces = 
    ipc timeout = 0
    kerberos keytab file = 
    kerberos service name = 
    kerberos support = no
    map to guest = never
    max active sessions = 1024
    max connections = 128
    max open files = 10000
    netbios name = KSMBD SERVER
    restrict anonymous = 0
    root directory = 
    server max protocol = SMB3_11
    server min protocol = SMB2_10
    server multi channel support = no
    server signing = disabled
    server string = SMB SERVER
    share:fake_fscaps = 64
    smb2 leases = no
    smb2 max credits = 8192
    smb2 max read = 4MB
    smb2 max trans = 1MB
    smb2 max write = 4MB
    smb3 encryption = auto
    smbd max io size = 8MB
    tcp port = 445
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    durable handles = no

    ; default share parameters
    browseable = yes
    comment = 
    create mask = 0744
    crossmnt = yes
    directory mask = 0755
    force create mode = 0000
    force directory mode = 0000
    force group = 
    force user = 
    guest ok = no
    hide dot files = yes
    inherit owner = no
    invalid users = 
    oplocks = yes
    path = 
    read list = 
    read only = ; yes
    store dos attributes = yes
    valid users = 
    veto files = 
    vfs objects = 
    write list = 

[example]
    comment = read only /tmp access
    path = /tmp

[tmp]
        comment = temp share
        path = /zPool/tmp
        create mask = 0774
        directory mask = 0775
        force group = admins
        hide dot files = no
    read only = no
        write list = henning,moni

